# C++ class template with a non templated class?

Tags: c++, templates

Compiling the following code

```
template<typename T>
class t1 {
};

class t1 {
};
```

Gives the following error

```
error: template argument required for ‘class t1’
```

It's literally been years since I've used C++ enough to delve into templates (I've decided to pick it back up and learn C++ 11/14), so I'm probably mistaken, but I thought this was legal.

Can someone advise?  If you wanted to do something like this, how would you go about doing it?

Comment: `If you wanted to do something like this` I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this.

Unlike a function template, a class template cannot be overloaded. `t1` has been declared as a class template, the only thing you can do is specialize it:

```
template <>
class t1<int> {
};
```

Comment: Of course, the whole point of templates is to avoid explicit specialization as was shown in the above example. The main point is that once you declare a template, it must remain a template.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something *like* this with variadic templates:

```
template<typename...>
struct myclass;

template<>
struct myclass<>{};

template<typename T>
struct myclass<T>{};
```

But I can think of little use other than template metaprogramming and you still have to use template syntax: `myclass<>`